# Using std::map or std::unordered_map when storing consecutive indices

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, binary-search-tree, unordered-map

I'm storing some data in a vector for various filepaths scanned, e.g. `std::vector<CustomData> mDataVector`. A search routine yields multiple indices in this vector where that `CustomData` matched some criterion, i.e. it spits another vector of indices (e.g. 0, 8, 1 for three items at indices 0, 8 and 1 in that vector that matched the search criterion). **This part cannot be changed since this vector interfaces with an old API I can't change right now.**

I also use a `std::map<size_t, std::string> mIndexToFilepath` to quickly retrieve the old filepath in that previous vector from the indices of the search API:

```
// when inserting new data..
std::string filepath = "C:\\...";
CustomData data = getCustomDataFromFilepath(filepath);
mDataVector.push_back(data );
mIndexToFilepath.emplace(mDataVector.size() - 1, filepath);
```

And then when searching

```
std::vector<size_t> matchingIndices = searchVector(mDataVector); // I can't change this API
for(auto i : matchingIndices) {
   // here I need the old filepath
   std::string original_filepath = mIndexToFilepath[i];
   .. do something with original_filepath..
}
```

Question: since these are consecutive indices, I thought of using a `std::map` instead of `std::unordered_map`. Will this somehow yield better performances during `mIndexToFilepath[i]` search? (Not sure actually, I guess it would be a O(logN) search vs a constant search when using `std::unordered_map`?) Should I switch to `std::unordered_map` here?

Comment: Why do you need a map for the indexes? Can't you just create a structure to hold both the data and the path, and store that in the vector?

Comment: Have you measured the function in production code and found that this is a bottleneck? I doubt that it matters which method you use.

Comment: With current multi-Ghz, multi-core CPUs unless one's dealing with hundreds of thousands of values, measuring any difference in performance will be very difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choosing between `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` comes down to if you care about ordering or lookup.

If you need ordering, then you want `std::map`, at the cost of slower lookup (logarithmic).

If you need fast lookup, they you want `std::unordered_map`, at the cost of no guaranteed ordering when looping.

However, in your case, since the elements have consecutive keys, why not just store the old file paths in a `std::vector<std::string>` where the elements align with your `std::vector<CustomData>`? Here you have the same ordering and the lookup is also constant time (and likely better then a hash map, since youre just jumping to an index rather than hashing the key).